# Calculating Inverse Tangent

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

When calculating the inverse tangent of a degree, the calculator will always give an angle between 90 degrees and –90 degrees. But I want to find the positive value of the negative angle.

Do I add 180 or 360 to the angle?

How do I know if I should add 180 or 360 to the negative angle.

Comment: The period of the tangent is $180°$.

Comment: I dont understand. Could you explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "positive value of the negative angle"...

A periodic function $f(x)$ has period $p$ if for all integers $n$, $f(x+np)=f(x)$. As Yves pointed out, $\tan x$ has a period of $180^\circ$, meaning that for all real $x$,

$$\tan x=\tan(x\pm180^\circ)=\tan(x\pm360^\circ)=\cdots$$

In particular, if $\tan x=y$ for some given $y$, then $x=\tan^{-1}y+180^\circ n$. By definition of the inverse tangent, $\tan^{-1}y$ is some angle between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, but it's not the only one that satisfies $\tan x=y$. To get other solutions, you have to add or subtract a multiple of $180^\circ$.

As an example, consider the equation

$$\tan x=1$$

A calculator will tell you that $x=\tan^{-1}1=45^\circ$, but it's also true that $\tan(225^\circ)=\tan(45^\circ+180^\circ)=1$, so $x=225^\circ$ is also a valid solution. Whichever multiple of $180^\circ$ you need to add depends on which domain you expect to find $x$. If $x\in(-90^\circ,90^\circ)$, then $x=45^\circ$; if $x\in(90^\circ,270^\circ)$, then $x=225^\circ$; and so on.

Answer (score 0):

$\ tanx=a$

$x=\ arctan(a) + k{\pi}$, $k\in Z$

Period of tangent function is ${\pi}$, it could be added $k{\pi}$, $k\in Z$

Since $f(x)=\tan(x)$ is bijective when $x\in(\dfrac{-{\pi}}{2},\dfrac{{\pi}}{2})$, then,   $f(x)=\ arctanx$ is defined as

$f:(\dfrac{-{\pi}}{2},\dfrac{{\pi}}{2}) \rightarrow R$,

Comment: How do I know what the value of k is?

Comment: $k$ is any integer, $k=....,-2,-1,0,1,2,...$

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if your angle looks reasonable when you are given a negative number.

For example: If you are trying to find the angle of 1, -4 you know that it must be in the IV quadrant [point 1, -4 in quadrant IV.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSCkY.png)

We know that ArcTan(-4/1) ~= -76 degrees and that -76 degrees = 360-76 degrees which gives us the degree 284. If you check the graph, you will find that 284 degrees is in the IV quadrant, meaning that the point (1, -4) is at 284 degrees.

Conversely, if the point were to be (-4, 1) you know that the answer must be in the III quadrant [point -4, 1 in quadrant II.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOYXF.png) ArcTan(1/-4) ~= **-14** degrees and -14 degrees is equal to 360-14 degrees which gives us the degree 346 which is in the IV quadrant.

Because we can tell that II != IV we know to add 180 degrees to our original number -14 instead, to obtain 180-14=166, which is how we determine that 166 is our degree for (-4, 1).